# Filter date in Generic List

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class defined as below.

```
public class Risk
{
   public DateTime RiskDate { get; set;}
   public string RiskStatus { get; set;}    
}
```

And I have a List of Risk as below

### RiskDate             RiskStatus

10/10/2001           High

15/10/2001           Low

21/10/2001           High

28/10/2001           Low

05/11/2001           High

08/11/2001           Low

I would like to find the date range from the list for a given date. For example, if my input date is 17/10/2001 then I would like to pull 15/10/2001 and 21/10/2001 from the list. If my input date is an exact match to the list, for example 28/10/2001, then I would like to pull only that date from the list.

I hope someone can advice me on this.

Thanks

Comment: what did you try so far? do you want to do this with LINQ or SQL? you should basically get the max of the lower AND the min of the greater unless you find an exact match.

Comment: What I did was sort the list and using a loop to find the index of the date which is equals or less. Then find the indexes of the range. But I would like to do it in LINQ possibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
var lower =
    from d in dates
    where d <= inputDate
    orderby d descending
    select d;

var upper =
    from d in dates
    where d >= inputDate
    orderby d
    select d;

var range = lower.Take(1)
    .Concat(upper.Take(1))
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: Implementing IComparable interface to the Risk class makes the above code worked as desired. Thanks

Comment: @Alan B - Since you were only working with dates I figured you could have also just selected the data property from your `Risk` class, but implementing `IComparable` would work too. Thanks.